# how to publish a feed of posts with a certain custom field value?

Tags: feed

In addition to the normal feed that wordpress produces, i need to publish an additional feed of posts that have a certain custom field value.

I'm a bit lost on where to start. Any tip?

Comment: Do you mean an rss feed?  Or do you just want multiple 'loops' of posts on a page?

Comment: yes i meant an RSS feed. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will add a /feed/special to your site.

```
add_feed('special','do_special_feed');

function do_special_feed() {
  query_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => 'key',
    'meta_value' => 'value',
  ));
  do_feed_rss2(false);
}
```

After putting it in a plugin or your theme's functions.php or what have you, you'll need to visit the Settings->Permalinks page at least once and save the settings, to get it to rebuild the permalink rules.

Comment: interesting. In the meantime i implemented a technique seen on Yoast, which works, but is more of a hack than your suggestion. http://yoast.com/custom-rss-feeds-wordpress/

Comment: Yeah, that method of the Page Template seems like a pretty weird hack when the ability to do this sort of thing easily is already built right in to WordPress. Creating custom feeds is easy.

Comment: I just tested this code. Any idea why after removing it from `functions.php`, the feed keeps available ?

Comment: Permalinks require a visit to the permalinks page to change. Also, check your caching plugins, if you have any.